# Adding a Notification Badge Icon to Android Devices

Tags: android, notifications

I am new to Android and I am wondering if there is a way to display a Notification Badge Icon on Android Devices similar to the way in which Apple devices work?

If so, could someone please explain how this is done.

I have a `GcmIntentService` and recieve the notifications in the Notification Centre and would like to know how to change the badge icon.

Comment: [View badger library](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

https://github.com/koduribalaji/ShortcutBadger

it will work only respected devices. it Works with LG, Sony, Samsung, HTC and other custom Launchers.

Comment: The instructions are not very clear, and I'm doing this in eclipse?

Comment: download the .zip file and extract it, then copy the ShortchutBadge class and past in your project and copy required files from that, and fix the errors.